# ¿Cómo omitir los registros cuando count devuelve 0?

Tags: sql

¿Cómo podría omitir los resultados del count cuando sale 0? mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
select 
MONTH(dFechaInicioC),
clave_final,
cur.vNombreC,
vNombreAI,
moda.vNombreM,
dFechaInicioC,
dFechaFinC,

(select COUNT (IDAlumno)
from sysInscripciones ins
left join catEstadosI est
on(ins.id_estatus=est.IDEstado)
where IDCurso=cur.IDCurso and est.IDEstado=2),

(select COUNT (IDAlumno)
from sysInscripciones ins
left join catEstadosI est
on(ins.id_estatus=est.IDEstado)
where IDCurso=cur.IDCurso and est.IDEstado=3),

(select COUNT (ins.IDCurso)
from sysInscripciones ins
left join catAlumnos alum
on (ins.IDAlumno=alum.IDAlumno)
where IDCurso=cur.IDCurso),

vNombreS,
sDuracionC,

(select count(IDProfresor)
from catNominas nom
where IDCurso=cur.IDCurso and vConceptoN like '%impartici%'),

cur.vCorreoC,
ticur.vTipoCurso,
DATEPART(QUARTER, dFechaInicioC)

from catCursos cur 
left join catAreasIngenieria areIng
    on (cur.IDAreaIngenieria=areIng.IDAreaIngenieria)
left join catCategorias cate
    on (cur.IDCategoria=cate.IDCategoria)
left join catSedes sedes
    on (cur.IDSede=sedes.IDSede)
left join catModalidades moda
    on (cate.IDModalidad=moda.IDModalidad)
left join catTiposCurso ticur
    on (cate.IDTipoCurso=ticur.IDTipoCurso)

where dFechaInicioC BETWEEN '2019/01/01' AND '2019/06/30' and bImpartidoC=1
```

[image: al momento de ejecutar la consulta me trae]

lo que quiere es que al ejecutar la consulta no me imprima los que tienen 0

Comment: Te recomendaria meter todo en un CTE y de ahi haces un where del campo donde no se incluyan los 0

Comment: ¿Que significa "no me imprima los que tienen 0"? ¿no mostrar la fila completa? ¿el 0 en que columna o columnas lo esperas filtrar?

Comment: Me refiero a que no me muestre toda la fila cuando sale 0

Comment: ¿Pero 0 en que columna?

Comment: en la décima columna, es decir que cuando el 0 de la décima columna salga, se pueda saltar el registro, es decir, que no lo muestre, la consulta la estoy utilizando en jasper para la creación de XLS

Answer (score 0):

podrías agregarle un alias (IDAlumnoCount) y después filtrarlo en el **where** general (IDAlumnoCount > 0), algo como esto:

```
(select COUNT (IDAlumno)
   from sysInscripciones ins
   left join catEstadosI est
   on(ins.id_estatus=est.IDEstado)
 where IDCurso=cur.IDCurso and est.IDEstado=2) as IDAlumnoCount,
...
where dFechaInicioC BETWEEN '2019/01/01' AND '2019/06/30' and bImpartidoC=1 and IDAAlumnoCount > 0;
```

Comment: la consulta esta colocada en jasperreport para generar un XLS

Comment: Así como está, esto no funciona. La subconsulta debe materializarse para poder acceder por el nombre de la columna. Esto funcionaría , si todo el `select` del AP lo colocas dentro de otro dónde ahí recién filtras por `IDAlumnoCount`. Saludos.

Comment: como es eso de colocar todo dentro de un select